# How to install Zettir on 22.04

Tags: 22.04, markdown

Zettir markdown editor seems to be found only in Arch. How can I get it on Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: Have you  tried the install manual on the webpage? At which point is the problem ?

Comment: Do you mean Zettlr? https://www.zettlr.com/

Comment: Marco: Maybe the problem was my misreading of the spelling. I copied the command from @Raffa, and was able to get Zettlr on my 22.04. Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Zettlr Markdown Editor](https://github.com/Zettlr/Zettlr) is available on Ubuntu 22.04 via [the `flatpak` package manager](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/flatpak.1.html) and should be simply installable by running:

```
flatpak update
```

Then, running:

```
flatpak install zettlr
```

Comment: That worked. I had some difficulty getting Flatpack installed and enabled, but eventually got Zettlr installed. I'm glad I copied the command you showed, rather than typing my misspelling. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Download the Debian x86_64 package here: https://www.zettlr.com/download/linux

By default, downloads will go to your directory *Downloads*. Install the package with:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo dpkg -i Zett*.deb
```